# Setting up JavaServer Faces in a spring project

Tags: spring, jsf

I want add support to JavaServer Faces to a spring project mine, but the tutorials I found on the web teach that for setting this to a project, add this line to the file **web.xml**:

```
   <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

but my spring project don't use  XML files for configuration, only java classes. Anyone can tell me how to configure JavaServer Faces in this scenario?

Comment: @peeskillet I don't have any deployment descriptor at all in my WEB-INF, because I am not using any XML file in my application. Because that I ask for a way to configure JSF through java code, like I do to other settings in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent class based configuration would be:

```
public class MyInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic facesServlet = servletContext.addServlet("Faces Servlet", new FacesServlet());
        facesServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        facesServlet.addMapping("/faces/*");
    }
}
```

More details [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)